# I designed a boost converter based off of a Texas Instruments schematic. Can't figure out why they're shorting out after a while

Tags: boost, converter, step-up, board, short-circuit

I designed my first DC to DC boost converter, which was primarily based off of the schematics that Texas Instruments provides for it in the datasheet, and then fine-tuned (applying specific component values) by using their WeBench online tool. The circuit is using a TPS61178 as it's boost converter IC.

The only thing I added to the circuit was a 3-phase AC bridge rectifier and capacitors at the input, since the circuit is powered by a 3-phase AC wind turbine.

I designed the circuit on easyeda.com and then used jlcpcb.com to have the PCBs assembled and mailed to me.

For some reason, two out of the five sample boards that I ordered have shorted between ground and the SW pin. The first board didn't last very long at all. In fact, it fried shortly after start-up. The second board worked quite well, but I barely had it running for more than 30 mins before it fried. The funny part, is that I've loaded it up and gotten it really hot, but it didn't short until a later time when it was running at a much lighter load.

I'm using these boards to power a USB Type-C charge board. The input voltage range is 3V to 17V, while the output is 18V. My wind turbine typically outputs 7V.

The only thing I did differently in the boost converter circuit was use a 2mOhm inductor instead of the 3.5mOhm inductor that the WeBench recommended.

Both boards seemed to have shorted to ground in the same place, and I think it's underneath the converter IC. The SW pin, PGND pin, and the VOUT pin run underneath the IC from one end to another. Again, it's the SW pin that shorted to ground. (The switch pin for the inductor).

The first board fired without anything connected to it. The second board fried while powering my USB charge board.

Am I missing an important component? Maybe I designed something incorrectly? Could this possibly be a quality control problem from JLCPCB? Maybe the short is internal to the IC?

Was really hoping someone's seen this before and can spot out something obvious that I missed.

Here's the schematic for my circuit:

(FYI: The datasheet requires the PGND and AGND to be connected at a single point, so I connected them underneath the IC, where the datasheet recommended.)

[image: Schematic for my circuit.]

Here's a link for the datasheet of the IC:

https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810010251_Texas-Instruments-TPS61178RNWR_C127918.pdf

Here's a pic of the top of the board:

[image: Board top view]

And here's a view of the bottom:

(Since the IC pins are about 0.254mm in width and very close to each other, I kept the copper trace widths at 0.254mm in order to avoid shorts. Since 0.254mm can only take so much current, I used a via on the far side of the SW pin and routed an extra trace of copper underneath to the inductor, just to provide more copper area.)

[image: Board bottom view]

Comment: Did the problem occur when connected to your wind turbine? What's the maximum voltage that your wind turbine can put out? Have you looked at the voltage on the input to the converter to be sure you're not approaching the maximum recommended value?  Did you do any validation with a lab supply on the input?

Comment: The first board shorted while connected to 12V DC from a regulated power supply. (The input range of the boost circuit is 3V to 17V). The second board shorted while connected to my wind turbine, which was generating around 7V.

Comment: OK- Since one board failed at no load (correct?) and you didn't exceed Vin max, is the converter unstable? Have you looked at the switch node and output voltage to see if there are signs of instability?

Comment: I would check if there is an error in the PCB, possibly shorting your circuit somewhere. I notice your EN (enable) pin running directly from the input voltage, but it should be fine.

Comment: The 2.2 µH inductor and the 10 µF output capacitors are intended for 500 kHz, but you set the frequency to around 200 kHz. Are you sure that your inductor does not saturate in this conditions? The current limit is set to 13 A. Test the board with much lower current limit first.

Comment: @Jens Same thing I forgot to mention, he should go with at least 3.3uH (the upper suggested value) as he's running at almost the lowest frequency.

Comment: _"Maybe the short is internal to the IC?"_ - unsolder the IC and test it for a short.

Comment: To the right of ACIN1 and CIN4, and along that vertical line I see spikes.  Are these on the PCB or am I just seeing artifacts?  I can't see jlcpcb letting that through, so it's probably artifacts or I'd check a bare board for shorts.

Comment: You might try testing a bare board using an insulation tester or HiPot. That should identify any place where spacing is insufficient, or if there are little copper "whiskers" as @StainlessSteelRat observed in their comment above.

Comment: @JohnD  regarding your comment about stability. One of the sample boards is much less stable than the others. With the board hooked up to my adjustable power supply and with a load connected to the output, whenever the input voltage drops below 7V, the output current and voltage fluctuates. This is bad, since it's supposed to operate with an input voltage as low as 3V. The other boards do not do this. While unloaded, it puts out 18V without an issue. I can also hear audible chatter when I lower the voltage with a load connected.

Comment: @Jens Hmmm, I'll have to re-engineer it then. I was copying the parameters that the webench tool told me to use, but maybe it's wrong. I never intended the output current to be 13A. I specifically set the webench tool to design the circuit for 1.5A output. I think I may have to stick to using only the datasheet. Not sure how I missed that the current limit is set to 13A. I never wanted it that high.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I hope that's not the case. Those lines were only visible in the online pcb layout tool. I hope they didn't transfer to the board! I'll give it a closer look.

Comment: @Jens I just looked up the peak current in  the datasheet again. It's supposed to be no more than 10A. I'm surprised I missed this, but I'm even more surprised that the load is pulling that much. My power supply shows that it's never pulling more than 3A on the input side. Is this irrelevant to the peak switching current?

Comment: The current you see on the power supply is an average value. You would not see inductor saturation or bad intermediate states there. Have a look at the conversion efficiency, input power versus output power. Values below 85 % are very suspicious.

Comment: The circuit tool showed me an efficiency of 87%. Just to see what would happen, I changed the inductor to 3.3uH and lowered the output current down to 1A instead of 1.5, then the efficiency jumped to 92%. It automatically changed the values of several other components too. The simulated frequency is now at 300kHz. I think what I did wrong previously, is that I ran the design tool and got a specific circuit, then manually changed the inductor to match one that was readily available for me, but what I forgot to do was re-calculate it so all of the other components were optimized to it.

Comment: @Jens Looks like my actual conversion efficiency is about 75%. I used an ammeter at the input and one at the output to calculate. It does get pretty hot too. I had it running at 12V 2A in and was getting around 18V 1A out. This specific board I tested has been operating fine for a while (besides getting hot). Not sure why the first two gave out so quickly; they're all the same.

Comment: 75 % is critical here, the circuit dissipates 6 W without heat sink! I assume you still use the 2.2 µH inductor and the relative low frequency of 200 kHz. I would recomment a larger inductor value, but if this is not possible, try to rise the frequency to lower the peak current. Use RFreq around 390 kohm for a test. However, there are inductors with a "slow" core, that cannot operate at the higer frequency. I don't know if yours can.

Comment: @Jens yes, I haven't made any changes to the circuit yet, just got a chance to test it some more yesterday. I'll certainly be redesigning it with a better inductor that matches the frequency. Although this is the first time I've heard of inductors with slow cores. Are they labelled as such? Just want to make sure I don't choose one of those by accident

Comment: Different core materials have different frequency ranges, where power losses are acceptable low. With ferrite you are on the safe side, with some iron powder cores you might get problems or bad efficiency at 500 kHz.